# Reputation transfer

Tags: support

I note that there was a merge between astronomy and physics SE some time ago, before another astronomy SE was made. My question is, that if there is even a similar transfer, would badges and reputation of a user on the transferred site be transferred over to the other site?

Comment: The likelihood of this iteration of Astronomy getting closed is extremely low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your questions directly,

> if there is even a similar transfer, would badges and reputation of a user on the transferred site be transferred over to the other site?

No. The reputation and badges will be recalculated/awarded according to the current status of the account after their posts have been migrated.

This is the side-effects of the standard **post migration**. From [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work),

> ### What is migration?
>
> Migration allows an off-topic question to be gracefully moved to another site in the Stack Exchange network. *It preserves the current revision of the question, all its answers, any comments on any post, as well as most of the votes.*
>
> #### Side effects of migration
>
> - *The destination question's score is reset to zero if the origin question had a negative score. Otherwise, its score is retained*, and the votes are attributed to the Community user.
>
>   - *The original scores are preserved for the answers*, with the votes (again) being attributed to the Community user.
> - **Answers on the origin site are deleted immediately** upon question migration. *(This causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the origin site.)* The answers will be visible on the destination question.
> - **The question is left as a stub**, or pathway to the new site, **for 30 days**, after which it is automatically deleted. During this time, the stub question will be locked to preserve the post in its original state, and prevent comments and votes. *(Again, this causes a reversal of all associated reputation on the origin site.)* Note that the old link will continue to redirect to the new question even after that time.
>
> <sup>(*Emphasis mine*)</sup>

So, reputation will be recalculated on both sites, and badges that are related to the post's score will be awarded again on the target site.

Note also that *badges cannot be taken after awarded* (except tag badge, because it depends on the amount of the answers and their score), so users can have *both badges* on the source and target sites after the migration.

---

Aside from that, it's also better to understand the reason for closing the old Astronomy.SE: **inactivity**. From [the Physics.SE meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/if-its-possible-do-we-want-to-expand-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-astrono) and [its linked blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/04/25/when-a-site-grows-quiet/),

> when a site struggles to maintain any semblance of steady progress — when it’s struggling to garner an audience, a healthy core of experts, and a steady stream of questions — it becomes increasingly unlikely that the site will find a core audience to sustain it.
>
> Next week, we’re shutting down six sites that fall into this category:
>
> - Astronomy

However, this site doesn't show any indicator of inactivity or in danger of getting shut down. **There would be a meta announcement from the Community Manager long before the shutdown.** So, there's no reason to worry about it :)